# Access variables defined in App.js, from class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to React-Native.
Say I have variables defined in App.js and I'm using Green.js as a class component for a button.
How is it possible to get access to someBool from Green.js?
The point is to use the state to change the color but the state has to change according to a condition I must define in App.js

App.js:

```
import Green from './components/Green.js'
export default class App extends Component{
    render(){
      let someBool; ....
```

Green.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View,TouchableOpacity, Button} from 'react-native';
//import App from './App.js'

 class Green extends Component {
     constructor(props){
         super(props)
         this.state={}
         this.state.custum={
            backgroundColor: 'darkgreen'
         }

         setInterval(() => {
             this.setState( {
                 custum:{
                     backgroundColor: 'lightgreen'
                 }
                })
         }, 1000);
     }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={[styles.greenB, this.state.custum]}>   // I WANT TO USE SOMEBOOL AS A CONDITION HERE
            </View>
        );
      }
    }  
    var styles = StyleSheet.create({
        greenB:{
          padding: 5,
          height: 80,
          width: 80,  
          borderRadius:160,    
          backgroundColor:'green',    
        },
    })
export default Green;
```

Please help me, 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should pass it down to the Green component.
In return of the render method in the App component where you called `<Green />` add a prop like `<Green someBool={someBool} />`. In the Green component you have access to it by `this.props.someBool`.